# How to get server response in dropzonejs

Tags: javascript, php, dropzone.js

I am using dropzonejs to upload images.

I want get server response once file successfully uploaded.

How can I get that?

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The question is good enough... but none of the answers explain the problem. The original success handler does not return a response object, you must overwrite it. This is specified in the source code here: https://github.com/dropzone/dropzone/blob/main/src/options.js#L574

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this.

HTML Code

```
<form id="myform" action="/youraction"></form>
```

JavaScript Code

```
Dropzone.options.myform={
  success: function(file, response){
      //Here you can get your response.
      console.log(response);
  }
}
```

In success method you will get latest uploaded file and the server response.
For more info. https://www.dropzonejs.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the success event.

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
  init: function() {
        thisDropzone = this;
        this.on("success", function(file, responseText) {
            var responseText = file.id // or however you would point to your assigned file ID here;
            console.log(responseText); // console should show the ID you pointed to
            // do stuff with file.id ...
        });
    }
};
```